# jQuery Deferred Won't Resolve

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-deferred

I have a service helper setup like this:

```
var service = {

getSettings: function () {

    var that = this,
     deferred = $.Deferred();

    that.getThingOne().done(function (data) {

        that.getThingTwo(data.Element).done(function (data) {

            deferred.resolve(data);
        });
    });
    return deferred.promise();
},

getThingTwo: function (elm) {

    return $.getJSON('http://ajax-call-here');
},

getThingOne: function () {

    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(deferred.resolve, deferred.reject, {
        enableHighAccuracy: true
    });
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

};

When I call into it doing something like this I never reach below. What is going on?

```
service.getSettings().done(function(data) {

    // never reach here
});
```

Comment: I don't see anything immediately wrong in your logic.  Did you insert `console.log()` statements and find out how far in your progression it got before you stopped seeing progress?

Comment: @aherrick, have you got this working yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First - You can simplify your code quite a bit. Promises chain and are an abstraction on the notion of continuation itself.

```
getSettings: function () {
    var that = this; // this line can be avoided as well
    return this.getThingOne().then(function (data) {
        // returning from a `.then` will cause the promise to resolve with that
        // return value
        return that.getThingTwo(data.Element); 
    });
}
```

Second, your promisification doesn't work. Try to preserve the context:

```
getThingOne: function () {

    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    function(v){ deferred.resolve(v); }, // preserve context
    function(e){ deferred.reject(e;) }, { // here too
        enableHighAccuracy: true
    });
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

Because of this - the promise never got resolved.

Comment: jQuery's `deferred.resolve` and `deferred.reject` methods are detachable; their context is bound in. So what the OP wrote is (syntactically) correct. Whether or not `...getCurrentPosition(deferred.resolve, deferred.reject, ...);` is a correct invocation of the API is another matter.

Comment: Your second issue is not a problem in jQuery (counterintuitive, but something jQuery has done).  You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/X6eLV/.  It remains a mystery why the OP's code doesn't actually work, but obviously your first suggestion is a much cleaner way to go.